# Выдает ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'files'

Tags: python

Выдает ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'files'

Подскажите из-за чего ? Что то устанавливать надо или где то ошибка?

Код файла shop_news.py

```
import os
from files.read import read_file
shop = {}

tree = os.walk('shop')
for elem in tree:


    def update_shop(dir_name ='shop', shop=shop):
    
        tree = os.walk(dir_name)
        for root, dirts, files in tree:
            for file in files:
                group = read_file('shop/' + file)
                group = group.split(' ')
                names = group[1::2]
                prices = group[2::2]

                products = {}

                products.update(zip(names, prices))

                shop.update({file:products})
            
                return shop

    update_shop()
```

код файла read.py

```
def read_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    message = ''
    for w in file:
        message += w

    return message

def create_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    return file
```

код ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python programms\files\shop_news.py", line 2, in <module>
    from files.read import read_file
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'files'
PS C:\python programms>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском!  Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1280409/edit))

Comment: А если так: `from read import read_file`

Comment: Разобрался вложенность файлов не та. Видимо под устал.